# Spring 4 @ControllerAdvice conflicts with @Transactional

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring web mvc application and I have a method annotated with @Transactional in the service layer. The controller evokes this method in the service. There is also a @ControllerAdvice annotated Advise class in the spring classpath.

Any RuntimeException that is thrown in the service method does not roll back and instead
the code inside the ExceptionControllerAdvice for handling RuntimeException is executed.

Should @ControllerAdvice not be used in conjunction with @Transactional?

Comment: The code inside `@ControllerAdvice` should of course be executed if an exception occurs anywhere from the `Controller` downward (and that goes uncaught obviously). The issue with your `@Transactional` handling is probably an issue with transaction management in general with your application. Please show some code so that people here can try to help out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I found out that the problem was with the `<tx-driven>` not in the correct level of application-context.xml, Once I moved it to the servlet-context.xml, the service was correctly intercepted by the `TransactionalInterceptor` first and then intercepted by the `@ControllerAdvise`. Thanks for the help again.